# SharedPreferences.getInstance() before class constructor

Tags: class, asynchronous, sharedpreferences, flutter

I have a custom NetworkUtil class that contains methods Future get() and Future post(). These two methods require use of bearer token value that is saved in SharedPreferences. This class has a default constructor that retrieves this token value from SharedPreferences using:

```
SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((res) {
  token = res.getString("token");
});
```

But this returns token value to late since it return Future.

How can i get token value before or faster? Now if method post() is called the token is not returned jet.

Comment: You mean, it's your constructor that fetch preferences ?

Comment: Correct. I see what you men, the method alone could fetch this... Will try.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little tricky.

1. Can you inject the token itself directly into `NetworkUtil` like below,

   ```
   class NetworkUtil {
   final String token;
   NetworkUtil(this.token);
   }

   //usage:
   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   token = prefs.getString("token");
   NetworkUtil networkUtil = NetworkUtil(token);
   ```
2. Do a `null` check before using token.

   ```
   class NetworkUtil {
     String token;
     NetworkUtil() {
       SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((res) {
         token = res.getString("token");
       });
     }

     Future post(postBody) {
       if (token != null) {

       } else {
         throw Exception("token is not there");
       }
     }
   }
   ```